# Install Node.JS on RedHat 6.3

Tags: path, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have downloaded the Node.JS `tar` from the official website. I now have to set `/home/admin/Desktop/node-v0.8.16-linux-x64/bin` as the working directory to run it from a terminal. However, I don't want to have to `cd` in that directory every time, and I don't want the `node-v0.8.16-linux-x64` folder on my desktop all the time.

Where is a convenient place to put the `node-v0.8.16-linux-x64` so that:

- it's "hidden" from the user (i.e. not on the desktop)
- I can run `node` from a terminal regardless of the current working directory (i.e. it's automatically in my path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was asked and [discussed on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed).

The short answer is to place the executable in $HOME/bin (creating the directory if necessary). Most shell initialization files include $HOME/bin in the user $PATH, but you may need to manually add it to your $PATH.

Assuming you are using `bash`, add to your ~/.bashrc:

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin